# Braintree - Hosted Fields PayPal amount unable to change

Tags: braintree

I am using Braintree Hosted Fields for checkout. I have added Paypal button like this

```
paypal: {
            container: "paypal-container",
            amount: 20.00,
            singleUse: true,
            currency: 'EUR',
        }
```

I want the customer to enter the amount as much as he wants. I have checked the docs but unable to find how it can be done with hosted fields.

One option I have is to refresh the page once customer change the amount in the form text fields but that will wasted a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

One way to do this is to have a two step process. Have the user provide the amount prior to calling `braintree.setup`. Once they enter the value, you can call `braintree.setup` in javascript, using the same parameters you currently have but setting the `amount` parameter to be whatever the user just entered. The user can then go through the rest of the authorization flow, and you can send the amount to your server, which will be used in a `Brantree.Transaction.sale` call to complete the purchase.

Comment: Thanks. I have done something like this. But it is not the very user friendly way. Braintree should introduce some api call to change the charged amount without fully reloading the form. Now I have a Paypal button and a credit card form on same page and whenever user changes the amount in the text field I have to call braintree.Teardown and then setup again, it takes about 3 to 5 seconds which is not good.